# Streamlit e-charts displaying empty chart

Tags: json, dataframe, datetime, streamlit, echarts

Trying to create a bar chart where data is read from the table. Sql query is fetching the data but chart is empty.

sql is dynamically created based on the StateType and Incoming_Date. The sql output is shown in the attached image.

Below code is an example for a bar chart that I used that I hope gives an idea. Thanks in advance

Code snippet:

StateType = st.selectbox("Status Type: ",
['ORC_TO_PAT_STATUS', 'PAT_TO_PROD_STATUS', 'PROD_TO_ORC_STATUS'])

```
LimitType = st.selectbox("Output Days: ",
                    ['Limit 20', 'Limit 50', 'Limit 100','Limit 200','Limit 300','Limit 500'])


if(st.button("Refresh Data")):
    st.write("Your Status is: ", StateType)
    sqlquery_string = "SELECT INCOMING_DATE,  case when " + StateType + " = 'PASS' then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end as   " + StateType +         ", COUNT(INCOMING_DATE) as DataCounts from  EDH_PT1_TEST.OMD.EDHTEST_COUNT_RESULTS WHERE (" + StateType + " = 'PASS' OR " + StateType +         "= 'FAIL') and result_date = (select max(result_Date) from EDH_PT1_TEST.OMD.EDHTEST_COUNT_RESULTS) GROUP BY INCOMING_DATE , " + StateType + " ORDER BY 1 DESC,2 DESC,3 DESC " + LimitType 
    st.write(sqlquery_string)

    sql_query = pd.read_sql (sqlquery_string, con)
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns = ['INCOMING_DATE', StateType])
    df['INCOMING_DATE'] = df['INCOMING_DATE'].astype(str)
    #
    
    newdf=df.set_index(StateType,inplace=False).rename_axis(None)
    st.table(newdf)
    st.table(df)

    st.write(json.dumps(newdf['INCOMING_DATE'].to_list()))


    st.write(json.dumps(newdf.index.values.tolist()))

    bar_options = {
    "xAxis": {
         "type":'value',

        "axisTick": {"alignWithLabel": True},
        "series":[{"data":json.dumps(newdf['INCOMING_DATE'].to_list()),"type":'bar'}]
   },
    "yAxis": {
        "type":'value',
        "data":json.dumps(newdf.index.values.tolist())
        #"axisLabel": {formatter: "{MMM} {yyyy}" },
        #"series": [{"data":json.dumps(newdf['Incoming_date'].to_list()),"type": 'bar'}],
    }
    }
    
    

    clicked_label = st_echarts(
    options=bar_options

     )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCRKt.png)

I tried to StreamLit e-chart type='bar'.

Expecting the chart to look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECync.png)

Chart is empty[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2SlI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax messed up. You are passing your `series` as a property of your axes but `series` is a component on its own (ie. needs to be in the upper most layer of the `options` object).

You can read up a little on the concepts of echarts [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#ECharts%20Basic%20Concepts%20Overview)

Your code should be working if structured like this:

```py
options = {
  "xAxis": { ... },
  "yAxis": { ... },
  "series": [
    {"data":json.dumps(newdf['INCOMING_DATE'].to_list()),"type":'bar'},
    {"data":json.dumps(newdf['Incoming_date'].to_list()),"type": 'bar'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Updated script 
        bar_options = {
        "xAxis": {type:'value'},
        "yAxis": {type:'value'},
        "series":[
            {type:'bar',"data":json.dumps(list(newdf['INCOMING_DATE'].items()),default=myconverter)},
            {"data":json.dumps(newdf.index.values.tolist(),default=str)}
            ]
        }

getting new error ,MarshallComponentException: ('Could not convert component args to JSON', TypeError('keys must be str, int.. None, not type'))

Tried default='str'  and
 if isinstance(obj, np.datetime64):
            return obj.__str__()

Comment: That is not an issue with eacharts but with your json parsing. I was assuming these objects were correct. You migth want to take a look at pandas [`to_json` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Matthias.<br/>
 
*After converting to **to_json** object, not sure how can I assign the json object to x and y axis of the echarts*


**result = df.to_json(orient="table")**

*to_json output:*
"data":[{"index":0,"INCOMING_DATE":"2023-12-05","ORC_TO_PAT_STATUS":"FAIL"},{"index":1,"INCOMING_DATE":"2023-12-04","ORC_TO_PAT_STATUS":"PASS"}

*echart code*
"yAxis": {type:'value'},
"series":[
            {type:'bar',"data":json.dumps(**result**)},
            **#{"data":json.dumps(result)}**
            ]

Comment: See the [echarts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.data) for the correct format.